# Youtube api event only applies to first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube-api

I'm making a slider with youtube videos in it that i want muted so i made this:

```
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
player = new YT.Player('video', {
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
});
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.mute();
}
```

This works! But only on the first video. Check the jsfiddle. If you pause the second video you can see the first one is muted. I tried looping the event but no luck

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mre4dvbe/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply this for every video.

You also need to use unique `id` values for the `iframe` elements.

So after changing the `id` to `video` for the first and `video2` for the second, the script

```
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
    player = new YT.Player('video', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
    player2 = new YT.Player('video2', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.mute();
}
```

now works

Update demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/mre4dvbe/2/

---

**Updated version** *after comments*

```
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
  var videos = document.querySelectorAll('.yt-video');

  [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) {
    new YT.Player(video, {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.mute();
}
```

This will work with any number of videos (*which share the same class `yt-video`*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/mre4dvbe/5/

Comment: Forgot to  mention but I cant do this. Because the iframes get loaded via a CMS so I dont know how many iframes there will be so i cant give them different classes/ids

Comment: ok, then you will have to identify them and apply the code. will update answer in a second

Comment: @C.Schubert can you edit the template so that the videos also have a class ? for example `class="yt-video"`

Comment: Yes I can. But i cant give them different classes.

Comment: ok, for the class we want it to be the same, but `id` must be diffreent because it is invalid.

Comment: I don't need my ids I understand i can't use multiple id's with the same name. So we can remove them and add classes instead with the same name. But now the mute event just has to execute on all the available iframe's with the classes

Comment: added update. (*just a heads up that you had the `id` twice on each video so the second one still remained in you update*)

Comment: on more thing is that i do not store the created players for each video anywhere. Are you using the `player` variable of you initial code for other communications with the video ?